# Linux stuck on booting automatically in x seconds

Tags: linux, boot

I've recently found an old HP Mini of mine, and its hard drive was on its last legs. I decided to replace the HDD (Win 7) with an SD card running Ubuntu.

The problem is, whenever I start the computer, the "Automatic boot in x seconds" keeps on repeating. I no longer have Windows so I can only use BIOS and some helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can approach the 'BIOS' settings, surely you can also adjust the boot order, [instructions for which can be found here, among other places](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=nl&lc=nl&dlc=nl&docname=c00364979).  I'd suggest getting a live USB and booting from there first to verify it is not an issue with the rest of the hardware.